# Why scipy.optimize.minimize does not work with a constraint and initial value 0

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize a function of two variables. I want one variable to be fixed at 50 and another be between -5 and 5. I wrote the following code:

```
x0 = np.array([50, 0.0])
res = minimize(error, x0, constraints=[
    {'type': "eq", "fun": lambda x: x[0] - 50},
    {'type': "ineq", "fun": lambda x: -abs(x[1]) + 5},
])
```

where `minimize` is a function from `scipy.optimize`.
The first constraint is `x[0] == 50` and second one is `-5 <= x[1] <= 5`.
I get the following response:  `message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'`. But when I set the second variable to be not zero (e.g. `x0 = np.array([50, 0.1])`) it finds a solution successfully. What can be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the constraints have to be differentiable. Have you tried expressing the `x[1]` constraint in terms of `x[1]**2` instead of `abs(x[1])`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Wow! Thank you! It worked. Write it as an answer if you want

Comment: Just a quick note, if you fix a variable's value then it is no longer a variable but a constant & a known so doesn't need 'optimizing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints need to be differentiable, and your second constraint is not. If you express the constraint in terms of `x[1]**2` instead of `abs(x[1])`, it should work. You could also eliminate the `abs` by splitting the constraint into two separate constraints, one for the upper bound and one for the lower bound.

Comment: By the way the second option does not work. Initially I created two constraints and I got the same error message as I got with abs function.